# OAuth authentication error in Facebook graph api

Tags: facebook

Using graph API `graph.facebook.com/103284669756289_575801289171289`

```
"error": {
      "message": "An access token is required to request this resource.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 104,
      "fbtrace_id": "E9N1FZBirds"
   }
```

getting this response while fetching particular id detail.

Comment: Can you tell how you are fetching results? Using graph API or SDK ?

Comment: Using graph API  https://graph.facebook.com/103284669756289_575801289171289

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/

Use Graph API Explorer from Facebook to test your API calls.I think your access token is missing for this call.

Its done. You just have to access_token in URL.
https://graph.facebook.com/103284669756289_575801289171289?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN

Comment: I tested this in explorer and got details for story.

  "story": "BCOD Web Solutions Pvt. Ltd. shared their photo."

Comment: Check and let me know if there is still an issue.

Comment: I'm getting this response from Graph API Explorer from Facebook, I want to get those response in iOs app and that error is still there when I call this url in chrome.

Comment: In chrome you are not sending access token. Same is the issue with iOS app as well (you missed access token). Can you share your code?

Comment: here is my code, NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/103284669756289_575801289171289"]];;
    NSMutableURLRequest *req=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    
    [req addValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [req setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

Comment: And what is the exact error your are getting as response?

Comment: Its done. You just have to access_token in URL.
https://graph.facebook.com/103284669756289_575801289171289?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN

Comment: {
   "error": {
      "message": "(#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: 103284669756289_575801289171289\"]]",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 803,
      "fbtrace_id": "GaZM6DG7pJk"
   }
}

Comment: Yes it Worked, I'm getting response. Till yesterday I was getting all response , Story, Picture, type, message now I'm not getting those nodes in response.

Comment: I want to fetch the detail of particular ID with using that particular Id

Comment: That is strange i use access_token and got all tags that you mentioned as missing.

"story": "BCOD Web Solutions Pvt. Ltd. shared their photo.",

"picture": "https://fb-s-d-a.akamaihd.net/h-ak-fbx/v/t1.0-0/s130x130/1528484_572246012860150_1506226946_n.jpg?oh=71b2bcdd08ee3f51b3764b3524568e67&oe=59B978DA&__gda__=1505194579_f1963978a20780110e512dee23c1abbc",
 
"type": "photo",

"message": "Happy New Year!!!",

Comment: I don't understand how you get data without access_token or Facebook session? As you said its working fine eariler. That's not possible at all.